# Javascript needed to keep active page link highlighted - html5 & css

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

I have read and tried numerous version of javascript and I can not seem to get my active page link to stay highlighted. Please help. Java script is not my thing.  Doc type is HTML5

Below is CSS

```
nav a:link   {
    color: #FFFDEF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
nav a:visited   {
    color: #FFFDEF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
nav a:hover   {
    color: #F38000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #101010;
}
nav a:active  {
    color: #F38000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #101010;
}
```

Below is HTML

```
<nav>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <a href="../index.html">HOME</a>
        <a href="../beefmaster-breedinfo.html">BREED INFO</a>
        <a href="../aboutwo.html">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="../awards.html">AWARDS</a>
        <a href="../news.html">NEWS</a>
        <a href="../farmandcattlereferencelinks.html">LINKS</a>
        <a href="../blackbeefmastergeneticshowtoeffectivelybreedthem.html">TIPS</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use Javascript? Your CSS works fine for keeping the active styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:active` only applies while the link is being activated (while the mouse button is being pressed). It is probably working in that regard. Perhaps you are looking for a way to identify which link matches the current page and apply some styling?

```
<body>
...
<script>
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
     document.querySelectorAll("#mainmenu a[href]"), 
     function(t) { 
        var hr = t.href.split("/").pop();
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(hr) > -1)
            t.className = 'active';
        else
            t.className = '';
     }
  );
</script>
</body>
```

And a CSS class like:

```
nav a.active,
nav a:active  {
  color: #F38000;
  background-color: #101010;
}
```

Comment: Why `querySelectorAll` when the Element is an ID? ID's are supposed to be unique. It would be faster to call `document.getElementById` And you can use `this.href` inside the callback of `forEach` instead of the fancy `querySelectorAll`. Just saying.

Comment: It's not selecting the element with the ID. It is selecting all `a` elements that contain an `[href]` property that are children of the element with the ID.

Comment: `var childNodes = (document.getElementBYId('mainmenu').childNodes).getElementsByTagName('a');`

Comment: Yes, that is the more cumbersome way of doing it we were bound to 10 years ago. .. now make it filter out elements without the href set.

Comment: Malk thank you for your answer, and I am looking for my link to stay highlighted while on that page so visitors are clear where they are with in the site as there will be multiple menus... I placed your javascript before the close of the body tag and added the css you provided to my style sheet. The result was all of my links staying highlighted... Again I know nothing about javascript....